# Why is Ubuntu not as fast when it was freshly installed?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, graphics, laptop, games

When I freshly installed Ubuntu on my laptop, it was blazing fast, but now it is very slow.... Games like TF2, MInecraft, DOTA 2, where working fine for like, 1 month, severe lag and lag spikes started...

Laptop specs:

- Memory: 1.7 GiB
- Processor: Intel Celeron(R) CPU B815 @ 1.60GHz x 2
- Graphics: Intel Sandybridge Mobile
- OS type: 64-bit
- Disk: 313.0 GB

***What should I Do?***

Comment: have you checked out this thread? http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/survival-mode/297111-howto-optimize-minecraft-for-linux

Comment: There is too little information to go on to help you what's wrong with your system.  First install `bootchart`, then read the manual, [edit] your question and post a chart.  Then we can give you guided information...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you've got a bunch of background services running...

1. smbd and nmbd

smbd and nmbd are daemon of Samba Process. Do you really need to export smb share on windows or other machine. If not! why are these processes running? You can safely kill these processes and disable them from starting automatically when machine boots the next time.

2. Telnet

Do You need bidirectional interactive text-oriented communication over internet or local area network? If not! kill this process and turn-off it from starting at booting.

3. rlogin

Do you need to log in to another host over network. If not! Kill this process and disable it from starting automatically at boot.

4. rexec

The Remote Process Execution aka rexec lets you execute shell commands on a remote computer. If you don’t require to execute shell command on a remote machine, simply kill the process.

5. FTP

Do you need to transfer files from one host to another host over Internet? If not you can safely stop the service.

6. automount

Do you need to mount different file systems automatically to bring up network file system? If not! Why is this process running? Why are you letting this application to use you resource? Kill the process and disable it from starting automatically.

7. named

Do you need to run NameServer (DNS)? If not what on earth is compelling you to run this process and allow eating up your resources. Kill the running process first and then turn-off it from running it at boot.

8. lpd

lpd is the printer daemon which makes it possible to print to that server. If you don’t need to print from the server chances are your system resources are being eaten up.

9. Inetd

Are you running any inetd services? If you are running stand alone application like ssh which uses other stand alone application like Mysql, Apache, etc. then you don’t need inetd. better kill the process and disable it starting next time automatically.

10. portmap

Portmap which is an Open Network Computing Remote Procedure Call (ONC RPC) and usages daemon rpc.portmap and rpcbind. If these Processes are running, means you are running NFS server. If NFS server is running unnoticed means your system resources are being used up un-necessarily.

How to Kill a Process in Linux
In order to kill a running process in Linux, use the ‘Kill PID‘ command. But, before running Kill command, we must know the PID of the process. For example, here I want to find a PID of ‘cupsd‘ process.

[avishek@tecmint]# ps ax | grep cupsd

1511 ?        Ss     0:00 cupsd -C /etc/cups/cupsd.conf

So, the PID of ‘cupsd‘ process is ‘1511‘. To kill that PID, run the following command.

[avishek@tecmint]# kill -9 1511

To find out more about kill command with their examples, read the article A Guide to Kill Command to Terminate a Process in Linux

How to Disable a Services in Linux
In Red Hat based distributions such as Fedora and CentOS, make use of a script called ‘chkconfig‘ to enable and disable the running services in Linux.

For example, lets disable the Apache web server at the system startup.

[avishek@tecmint]# chkconfig httpd off

[avishek@tecmint]# chkconfig httpd --del

In Debian based distributions such as Ubuntu, Linux Mint and other Debian based distributions use a script called update-rc.d.

For example, to disable the Apache service at the system startup execute the following command. Here ‘-f’ option stands for force is mandatory.

[avishek@tecmint]# update-rc.d -f apache2 remove

After making these changes, The system next time will boot without these UN-necessary process which in-fact will be saving our system resource and the server would be more practical, fast, safe and secure.

That’s all for now. I’ll here we again with another interesting article. Till then stay tuned and connected to Tecmint. Don’t forget to provide us with your valuable feedback in comment Section.

http://www.tecmint.com/remove-unwanted-services-from-linux/

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...

Comment: Working on that ^

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, Ubuntu, despite being fairly power-efficient, can consume RAM quite quickly, and once it starts using swap, I've found that it bogs down immensely. I'd check your RAM usage using the system monitor (run it from the Unity dash or with `gnome-system-monitor` in the terminal). If RAM looks like an issue, you can try trimming down background processes, as Daniel suggested, or just look into a RAM upgrade. You might also look into adjusting your swap partition size and/or your swappiness value.

The system monitor may also indicate heavy CPU load, which would be trickier, as CPUs are rarely easy to swap out. Of course, background processes may also lighten CPU load, but I'm not sure what else could make it more efficient.